# Ограниченный прицел (UNITY3D)

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я в очередной раз делаю 2D игру, на этот раз это шутер, где игрок стреляет арбузами. Все было хорошо, пока я не дошел до реализации прицела. Дело в том, что я хочу ограничить дальность стрельбы игрока, то есть чтобы он стрелял только в определенном радиусе, а если курсор мыши выходит за пределы этого круг, то длина полета снаряда равна радиусу.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Черным кругом обозначена зона в пределах которой может стрелять игрок. На данный момент у меня есть метод для прицеливания, в котором собственно должно вычисляться положение прицела

```
    private void Aim()
{
    transCrosshair.localPosition = difference;
}
```

И метод который создает снаряд, задавая ему вектор на который он переместиться

```
    private void SpawnProjectile(FakeHeightObject projectile)
{
    projectile.transform.position = transGunTip.position;
    projectile.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    projectile.Initialize(difference * power, verticalVelocity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос и вот как рассчитать вектор

```
    mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    difference = mousePos - transGun.position;
    dir = difference.normalized;
    cursorVector = dir * power;

if (difference.magnitude < cursorVector.magnitude)
    {
        cursorVector = difference;
    }

    transCrosshair.localPosition = cursorVector;
```

Далее мы просто передаем значение cursorVector в метод

```
    private void Aim()
{
    transCrosshair.localPosition = cursorVector;
}
```